# How to Reliably Check if a Javascript String is a Number

Tags: javascript, types, numbers

How do you determine if a string represents a number?

The straightforward and potentially naive way is this:

```
function is_number(my_str) {
  return !isNaN(parseInt(my_str));
}
```

However, **the above does not work**. Notice that the following all return true:

```
is_number("3, 4, 5");
is_number("3, (123)");
is_number("3, 123)");
is_number("3, (123) (and foo bar)");
is_number("3 apples and 2 oranges");
```

The issue is that `parseInt` seems to only look at the first word. Any idea on a more comprehensive solution here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Number()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number).
`parseInt` and `parseFloat` converts `String` to Number if first character is a number. But `Number()` checks for whole `String`.Number return `NaN` if whole string is not number

```js
function is_number(my_str) {
  return !isNaN(Number(my_str)) && Boolean(my_str) || my_str == 0;
}

console.log(is_number("3, 4, 5"));
console.log(is_number("3, (123)"));
console.log(is_number("3, 123)"));
console.log(is_number("3, (123) (and foo bar)"));
console.log(is_number("3 apples and 2 oranges"));
console.log(is_number(null));
console.log(is_number(undefined));
console.log(is_number(0));
console.log(is_number('0'));
```

Comment: Getting close, but notice `is_number(null) == true`

Comment: I know I'm expanding the scope of this function slightly, but notice: `is_number(0) == false`

Comment: @speedplane ok now check.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

```js
console.log(Number("3, 4, 5") || false)
console.log(Number("3, (123)") || false)
console.log(Number("3, 123)") || false)
console.log(Number('123') || false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my regular-expression based effort:

```
function isNumber (string) {
  return /^-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$/.test(string);
}
```

Includes support for leading sign, decimal places and exponent.

If it returns `true`, the string can be converted to a number using `JSON.parse`:

```js
function isNumber (string) {
  return /^-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$/.test(string);
}

function convertNumber (string) {
  if (isNumber(string)) {
    return JSON.parse(string);
  }
}

[
  '0',
  '1.2',
  '-3.4',
  '5.6789e100',
  '0.1e-100',
  '0.1e+100',
].forEach(string => {
  console.log(`isNumber('${string}'):`, isNumber(string));
  console.log(`typeof convertNumber('${string}'):`, typeof convertNumber(string));
});
```